# Is it possible to convert a generic json object to a dictionary type?

Tags: java, jackson

I don't want to know what is inside a json object, there could be anything in it.

```
{"a":"value1","potato":"[{another json}]","whatever":"value2"....}
```

I don't want to create a pojo with every possible key as keys are a lot.
So, I was wondering if I could just map a json object in a dictionary type, for example an hashmap.
This would allow me to have this map and retrieve values thanks to json keys, for example:

```
map.get("a"); //value1 here
```

I am using jackson as library.

Comment: And how is it going? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson mapper, you can specify `Map.class` as the type of the bound target, and you'll get a map for JSON structs.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `org.json.JSONObject` from your input `String`, like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"a\":\"value1\",\"potato\":\"[{another json}]\"}");
```

Then you can simply retreive any value using a `get` method with a chosen key as `String`, just like in a typical `Map`, like this:

```
json.get("a");
```